# what internal mechanism allows istringstream::iss to know that it is nested within a for loop

Tags: c++

The following code was taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/)

```
// istringstream constructors.
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream
#include <string>       // std::string

int main () {

  std::string stringvalues = "125 320 512 750 333";
  std::istringstream iss (stringvalues);

  for (int n=0; n<5; n++)
  {
    int val;
    iss >> val;
    std::cout << val*2 << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}


Output:
250
640
1024
1500
666
```

I understand that iss has an internal delimiter to recognize spaces. But how does it autonomously move to the next number after every loop?

It seems like the compiler has a built-in method that allows iss to move further every loop. 
But how?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not tag C++ as C.

Comment: Did you see this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg ?

Comment: It's not `iss` itself that advances, it's the `operator>>(istream, int)` that does the advancing. It's the same way as for `cin`, `ifstream`, etc...

Comment: Doing `iss >> val` reads as many characters as it can (starting from the current position in the buffer of the stream) that can represent an integer. It stops when it hits the end of the string or a whitespace character. `is >> val` also ignores any leading whitespace (moves the current position forward until it hits a non-space character, then starts reading).

Comment: It doesn't know it is inside the _for-loop_. The [operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) overload accepting `int` simply extracts the value into an `int` variable and moves some internal position indicator. The next statement inside the loop executes and so on. You have multiple calls to `operator>>`.

Comment: @Slava thank you. that seems like what I'm looking for( I hope)

Comment: @Ronn well it's this "internal position indicator" I'd like to understand. Thanks nonetheless

Comment: @MarcoBonelli why not? I feel like this case is an exception since this is about an internal mechanism, not surface level syntax. During my research, I often found myself on c code reference pages. In fact, this could even apply to java.

Comment: Simply put: because C is not C++. If you want to ask about a feature of a language, then tag only with that language. Tagging multiple languages only causes confusion and leads to misleading answers.

Comment: The specifics of tracking the position are deliberately left fuzzy to accommodate the many different types of streams. You can seek around inside a file or a memory block easily enough, but a keystroke buffer, a serial port, or a network socket are all quite fluid. Seeking forward is often futile because future data doesn't exist yet. Seeking backward might also not be possible because the data has been sent or moved on out of the buffer to free up space for future data.